# Unable to use fugitive.vim on gVim on Windows 7

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I am using gVim on Windows 7 and I have tried installing fugitive.vim  as described [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).

As per the link , I have extracted fugitive.vim to 
`vim73/plugin` folder which is in the runtime path for my gVim. But when I restart the gVim, I get "Not an editor command" message when I type in `:Gedit` , or `:Git` and also `:h fugitive` isn't giving a help page.

Also, I tried using the recommended pathogen.vim method as described [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen). I extracted `pathogen.vim` into my `vim73/autoload` folder and then created a bundle folder in gVim home directory(c:\Program Files\Vim). I extracted `fugitive.vim` into the bundle folder.
Updated the _vimrc file with the `execute pathogen#infect()` command and restarted gVim, but no luck..

Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it difficult to get fugitive working on Windows.

I do have a few things for you to try, found using `:h plugin`.

```
:echo has("eval")
```

If this returns 0, your build of vim/gvim does not support plugins.

```
:echo g:loaded_fugitive
```

If this returns an error, vim did not spot your plugin during start, check `:h plugin` for correct directories to install to.

If this returns 1, as mine did and it still did not work, try adding `set shellslash` to your .vimrc file.  This got mine working.

Comment: for me , `echo has("eval")` and `echo g:loaded_fugitive` return 1. I added `set shellslash` in `_vimrc` file. But unfortunately, this doesn't work either. Btw, I am checking by going to an exisiting git repository on my system and then using `:Gstatus` in gVim.

Comment: Since g:loaded_fugitive is 1, you have fugitive installed.  One more thing is that you have to be in a git directory for fugitive commands to work.

Comment: yes I gave the `:Gstatus` command after going into a directory I have intialized as git repository using `git init`

Comment: fugitive's commands aren't activated until you open a *file* in a git repo. Try that before `:Gedit` et al.

Comment: Download fugitive.vim version 2.2 from https:github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive
Install cygwin with git.exe on win7 in your path, Install gvim8. In cmd prompt > gvim  "+:so path/to/fugitive.vim" +:GV some-git-file.txt.  But  I couldn't get the newer fugitive.vim to work on win7.

Comment: My copy of fugitive is here https://github.com/moshahmed/vim/tree/master/fugitive just source and :GV (works on linux/mac/windows)